# Meteor select option selected in with loop

Tags: meteor

Meteor select tag dynamically how it selected.Please help me.

```
{{#with api_method_data_chnage}}
    <select id="result_type"> 
    <option value="{{ result_type }}"> {{ result_type }}</option>
    </select>
{{/with}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#conditional-attributes-with-no-value-eg-checked-selected

```html
<option value="{{ result_type }}" selected={{isSelected result_type}}> {{ result_type }}</option>
```

Now you just need to create the helper `isSelected` and make it return `true` or `false` depending on if the argument is the selected one or not.

Comment: Please provide the example.@Peppe L-G

Comment: value="{{ result_type }}" not displaying when we see in console also.Please help me.